# Java (netbeans): The database is connected to SQL Server, i need to update, and delete data from the netbeans interface

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc

the data is being view for this code by the interface:

```
private void distable() { 
    try { 
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=77OOP062;user=sa;password=hnd";
        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        String sql ="Select * from Customer"; 
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); 
    } 
}
```

and this is my update button code:
// i dont know how the code work over here
and this is my delete button code:

```
String query = 
  "DELETE FROM 'Customer' WHERE CustomerName=" 
    + jTextFieldCustomerName.getText();
executeSQLQuery(query,"Delete"); //error on this executeSQLQuery code
```

Comment: Print the content of `query` and see what's wrong with it .

Comment: thank you so much for the instant message..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one instead of using executeSqlQuery, use this:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();    
pst.executeUpdate(query);
```